# How i can exclude Django database in Django 1.9

Tags: python, django

I'm wondering how to exclude the database from my django app, that doesn't really need one, i've deleted the DATABASES tuple (or simply made it an empty tuple), but he gives me this erros:

```
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

How i can figure out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the minimum you have to apply in your settings, if you don't want a database:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': '',
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

if you still get the error try this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man! and what about the sessions? these will be managed in memory or in a file? what are your advice?

Comment: Unfortunately, i've tried your solution, but it continue to give me: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

Comment: Regarding sessions check out this page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/. I use `SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies'` btw.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this approach:

```
DATABASES = {}
```

And disabled Authentication middleware, as you can see in over there:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',    
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
#'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
# Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
# 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

)